# How to write the SQL select query to get the 4 different columns in 4 different tables even though they don't have direct relationship

Tags: sql

I need to get the director first name, last name, movie title and Avg of number of ratings for that movie using directors, movies, ratings table.

I tried to write it but there is no direct link between movie table and directors table. please help on this

[image]

Comment: Please do not use images in your post (much less an image of a photograph...)

Comment: You have to `JOIN` `movies` with `movies_directors` and then `JOIN` again with `directors`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to include a table in the join from which you don't need to return any fields, but which is needed to get to the data you *do* need. Here we'll include the table `movies_directors` as we need that to get the relationship between `movies` and `directors`:

```
SELECT d.DIRECTOR_FIRST_NAME, 
       d.DIRECTOR_LAST_NAME,
       m.MOVIE_TITLE,
       AVG(r.NUMBER_OF_RATINGS)
  FROM MOVIES m
  INNER JOIN RATINGS r
    ON r.MOVIE_ID = m.MOVIE_ID
  INNER JOIN MOVIES_DIRECTORS md
    ON md.MOVIE_ID = m.MOVIE_ID
  INNER JOIN DIRECTORS d
    ON d.DIRECTOR_ID = md.DIRECTOR_ID
  GROUP BY d.DIRECTOR_FIRST_NAME, 
           d.DIRECTOR_LAST_NAME,
           m.MOVIE_TITLE
```

Give that a try - modifying it as needed.

Comment: dang haha I'm too slow, I'll go ahead and delete my answer